# Can an mmo be made using websockets?

Tags: websocket, webgl

As the title suggests,

Would it be possible to make a 3D MMORPG like runescape using websockets for connection and webgl for graphics?

Answer (score 2):

From [Quake II GWT Port](http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/) web page (bold mine):

> The Quake II GWT port brings the **3d** gaming experience of Quake II to the browser.
>
> In the port, we use **WebGL**, the Canvas API, HTML 5  elements, the local storage API, and **WebSockets** to demonstrate the possibilities of pure web applications in modern browsers such as Safari and Chrome.
>
> [...]
>
> To make the Jake 2 code work with GWT, we have
>
> - Created a new **WebGL based renderer**
> - Ported the network layer for **multiplayer games from UDP to the WebSocket API**

I don't know much about MMO, but apparently someone already implemented quite impressive game in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets is for sure the bestoption when it comes to communication from a browser.

I do alot of work myself with WebSockets and has developed several different types of communication-intensive applications aswell as i developed a framework for realtime communication - Should you build for the web and HTML5 so WebSockets option.

A good start, or a way to quickly try out WebSockets is via http://live.xsockets.net, a service that provides a JavaScript API and a hosted WeSocket Server.

Kind regards

Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Lightstreamer among your options? It leverages HTTP and WebSockets, uses TCP but tries to overcome some of its limits with some smart algorithms to keep the latency low and optimize the bandwidth. It can automatically choose the best available data transport for each client - by default, it would use WebSocket, but it can fall back on HTTP streaming or even long polling if necessary. This makes a very robust communication protocol that can deliver to any known clients. Plus, it's highly scalable, so it can be used with great benefits for any multiplayer games of any complexity (including MMORPGs, for example).

Check this recent article ([Optimizing Multiplayer 3D Game Synchronization Over the Web](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html)). You can walk through an online demo of a very simple multiplayer 3D world in which Lightstreamer has been integrated for real-time synchronization. The demo allows you to tweak each parameter of the scenario and simulate any flavor of data delivery, while checking the actual bandwidth consumption. You can get your own hands dirty if you want, as the full source code is available for free on GitHub.

Hope that helps. Just let me know if you need some help!

[full disclosure: I work for Lightstreamer]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 6 years old, but someone must mention [BrowserQuest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/)

I have some experience with HTML5 game development (Phaser), but I have absolutely no experience with MMOs, tho I'm also very interested on starting developing something similar to BQ someday.

**UPDATE: I made one**
I made the first Deno based websocket *tiny* online RPG: [tiny land](https://github.com/tiny-devs/tiny-dungeon-online/)